# error running ant target

Tags: java, ant, junit, target

So i'm having some trouble with a new target within my build.xml file

```
<target name="consistency">
<description>Consistency</description>
<junit printsummary="withOutAndErr" haltonfailure="yes" haltonerror="yes" dir="${basedir}" showoutput="true" fork="yes" forkmode="once">
 <classpath refid="build.classpath" />
 <batchtest todir="${test.dir}">
  <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}/com/the/dir/is/correct/">
          <include name="ConsistencyCase.java" />
  </fileset>
 </batchtest>   
</junit>
```

This is failing because of an error:

```
    [junit] Running ConsistencyCase
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec

BUILD FAILED
D:\Users\myusername\workspace\projectname\build.xml:410: Test ConsistencyCase failed

Total time: 1 second
```

I cant figure out where the error is, due to the total lack of logs.
How can i let Ant to flush some error logs?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a formatter something like this:

```
<target name="consistency">
    <description>Consistency</description>
    <junit printsummary="withOutAndErr" 
            haltonfailure="yes" 
            haltonerror="yes" 
            dir="${basedir}" 
            showoutput="true" 
            fork="yes" forkmode="once">
        <classpath refid="build.classpath" />
        <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" /> 
        <batchtest todir="${test.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}/com/the/dir/is/correct/">
                <include name="ConsistencyCase.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>   
    </junit>
</target>
```